# Join an array with a block natively

Tags: ruby

Is there a native way to join all elements of an array into a unique element like so:

```
[
  {a: "a"},
  {b: "b"}
].join do | x, y |
  x.merge(y)
end
```

To output something like:

```
{
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
}
```

The fact that I used hashes into my array is an example, I could say:

```
[
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3
].join do | x, y |
  x + y
end
```

Ends up with `6` as a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) covers both of these cases:

```
a = [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}]
a.inject(:merge) #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}
b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b.inject(:+) #=> 6
```

`inject` "sums" an array using the provided method. In the first case, the "addition" of the sum and the current element is done by merging, and in the second case, through addition.

If the array is empty, `inject` returns `nil`. To make it return something else, specify an initial value (thanks @Hellfar):

```
[].inject(0, :+) #=> 0
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but when I tried it I forgot the initial value (for hashes) and it seems to work even without it ??

Comment: @Hellfar: Turned out I was misremembering the behavior of `inject`; it uses the first value of the array as the initial value by default, not zero, which explains why your code worked. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Finally, there is still a reason why we would need an initial value :) . If the array is empty the returned value of `inject` will be `nil`, in some case that could be not expected.

Comment: @Hellfar: True -- I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
[
  {a: "a"},
  {b: "b"}
].inject({}){|sum, e| sum.merge e}
```

Comment: `[...].inject { |sum, e| sum.merge e }` is sufficient. See comments on @Linuxios' answer.